# Pass Error Code from a VBA module to the VBScript that executed it

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

How can I successfully pass an error code from the VBA module in Part 2 to the VBScript that executed it in Part 1?

---

**Part 1: VBScript that executes the VBA in Part 2**

```
Option Explicit

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear

  Set xlApp = GetObject("","Excel.Application")
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\(directory)\(File Name).xlsm", 0, True)
  xlApp.Run "(Macro Name)"
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Msgbox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " The script will now quit."
      WScript.Quit
  Else
      Msgbox Err.Number
  End If
  xlApp.Quit
```

**Part 2: VBScript that executes the VBA in Part 2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub (MacroName)()

            'Snip - A bunch of working code                

            Err.Number = 7
            Err.Description = "Made up error for testing - delete me"

End Sub
```

---

When this script is run, Err.Number is 0 when tested, and the Msgbox simply displays `0`. What do I need to do to get it to display `7: Made up error for testing - delete me The script will now quit.`

Comment: Pass it as an argument?

Comment: @findwindow Would you do so similar to Mat's Mug's answer below?

Comment: I don't know vbscript.

Comment: @HuguesPaquetBlanchette I rejected your suggested edit for `excel` tag, but if you can point me to some meta that says we should use broader tagging in addition to narrower tagging I will approve the edit. I don't know what the meta verdict on the topic is.

Comment: @findwindow me neither! It's really just like VBA, but without explicit types, and it doesn't *need* `Sub` or `Function` procedures to run, since it's a "script".

Comment: @Mat'sMug tha'ts more than I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IntelliSense doesn't show it, but `Application.Run` is a `Function` with a `Variant` return type, so you can have a macro like this:

```
Public Function Test() As Integer
    Test = 42
End Function
```

And then the debug/immediate pane would output this:

```
?Application.Run("test")
 42
```

Make `(macro name)` a function that returns the error number, and then instead of this:

```
xlApp.Run "(Macro Name)"
```

You could do that:

```
Dim result
result = xlApp.Run("(Macro Name)")
```

And then check for the value of `result` instead of that of `Err.Number`.

---

Now, if `(macro name)` is *also* supposed to be called *as a macro* by Excel, changing it to a `Function` will make your VBScript work, and will break the Excel macro.

You could make a "wrapper" function to leave the macro exposed as a `Sub` for Excel to use, and call the wrapper function from VBScript:

```
Function VBScriptMacroNameWrapper() As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    ' run macro sub here
    VBScriptMacroNameWrapper = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```